# ReST Endpoint URL for CF cluster - Do I need a Gateway?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Apologies if this is a silly question.
I have a Spring-Boot application packaged as a jar file.
When I deploy it to CF (cf push) the ReST endpoint is available based on the CF application context.
Now, if I have CF scale this application over multiple nodes, does CF automatically handle the routing of ReST calls to the application instance or do I need to add a gateway like Netflix eureka/zuul to my application?
Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests to apps running on Cloud Foundry flow through the Cloud Foundry gorouter which will automatically load balance the requests to all your instances. You do not need Eureka or Zuul to get loadbalancing to your rest end point.

Eureka is useful in you have apps deployed to Cloud Foundry that you pushed without a route and are using container to container networking and client side load balancing.